# Partial Resonance Widths

Tags: gamma-rays

Can any one tell me how we calculate the partial width of a resonance reaction? If a proton beam of certain energy is incident on a Carbon nucleus, a 13C(p,gamma)14N reaction takes place and we have a resonance gamma peak. How do we calculate the total resonance width and partial resonance widths for this reaction? What is the relation between J, Er and the incoming proton? How can I find these parameters using energy level diagram? I know the resonance width is Planck's constant/ decay time of that particular energy level.

I need help to find these parameters.

I would like to know how to determine Γ(proton) and Γ(gamma). when a proton of certain energy e.g 5.5 MeV hits a C13 nucleus the de-excitation of nucleus occurs and a certain resonance occurs at relative energy level e.g 3.09 MeV , in this case the partial width of incoming particle is Γ(proton) and outgoing is Γ(gamma) my question is how to determine these two. and if τ = 1/Γ is used in case we know the decay time of that level in c13 so that resonance width is of incoming or outgoing , I guess outgoing than how to know the resonance width of incoming.

Comment: Sidra malik: Relevant is certainly the [Breit-Wigner distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Breit%E2%80%93Wigner_distribution) which calculates the cross-section of a resonant process as function of center-of-mass energy, and with (full) width $\Gamma$ as parameter. The general shape of this distribution is shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution); and the experimental results specificly of the 13C(p,gamma)14N reaction, with applicable fits, in Figure 70 of the [Nuclear Astrophysics Compilation of REactions (NACRE II)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7099).

Comment: thanks for comment , but i would like to know how to determine Γ(proton) and Γ(gamma). when a proton of certain energy e.g 5.5 MeV hits a C13 nucleus the de-excitation of nucleus occurs and a certain resonance occurs at relative energy level e.g 3.09 MeV , in this case the partial width of incoming particle is Γ(proton) and outgoing is Γ(gamma) my question is how to determine these two. and if τ = 1/Γ is used in case we know the decay time of that level in c13 so that resonance width is of incoming or outgoing , i guess outgoing than how to know the resonance width of incoming.